# Sql problems assistance please

Tags: java, android, sql

Hi fokes I am building an android app and I need to make an sql database to save time and score.

I would also like to get how many times it has been saved so I can use it to give the user times played.

Basically I need the sql to have on create 10 seconds and 0 score. Then after every play I would like it to have more times lets say 10.01 seconds ( more or less it doesnt matter) and to save the score.

Now when I run the game it works but when it has to do anything with the sql database it crashes.

Here is my sql database java code:

> package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;
>
> import android.content.ContentValues; import android.content.Context;
>   import android.database.Cursor; import
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
>
> public class spremanje {
>       public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
>       public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
>       public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
>
> ```
> private static final String IME_TABLICE = "bodovi";
> private static final String TABELA_BAZE = "nmvz";
> private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
>
> private DbHelper ourHelper;
> private final Context ourContext;
> private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
>
> private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>
>     public DbHelper(Context context) {
>         super(context, IME_TABLICE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_BAZE + " (" +
>                         KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
>                         KEY_TIME + " INTEGER , " +
>                         KEY_SCORE + "INTEGER )"
>         );        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();         int time=10000;
>       cv.put(KEY_TIME, time);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_BAZE);
>         onCreate(db);
>
>     }
> }
>
>
> public spremanje(Context c) {
>     ourContext = c;
> }
>
> public spremanje open() {
>     ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
>     ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
>     return this;
> }
>
> public void close() {
>     ourHelper.close();
> }
>
> public long createEntry(int time, int score) {
>     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
>     cv.put(KEY_TIME, time);
>     cv.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
>     return ourDatabase.insert(IME_TABLICE, null, cv);
> }
>
> public int getRed() {
>     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TIME, KEY_SCORE};
>     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(IME_TABLICE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
>     int red = 0;
>
>     int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
>
>     for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
>         red = c.getInt(iRow);
>     }
>
>     return red;
>
> }
>
> public int getTime() {
>     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TIME, KEY_SCORE};
>     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(IME_TABLICE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
>     int time = 10000;
>
>     int iTime = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME);
>
>
>     for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
>         time = c.getInt(iTime);
>
>     }
>
>     return time;
>
> }
>
>
> public int getScore() {
>     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TIME, KEY_SCORE};
>     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(IME_TABLICE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
>     int score = 0;
>
>     int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);
>
>
>     for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
>         score = c.getInt(iScore);
>
>     }
>
>     return score;
>
> } }
> ```

Here is my game activity:

```
package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;


public class Game extends Activity {
    TextView tekst, vrijeme;
    int brojac=0, provjera=0;
    CountDownTimer Count;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        spremanje read = new spremanje(this);
        read.open();
        int brojacvremena=read.getTime();
        read.close();
        tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
        vrijeme=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vrijeme);
        final Intent i =new Intent(Game.this,Score.class);
        vrijeme.setText("Time: "+brojacvremena/1000 + "." + brojacvremena%1000);
        /*AdView adView=(AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView123);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);*/
        Count = new CountDownTimer(brojacvremena, 1) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                vrijeme.setText(seconds + "." + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish(){
                i.putExtra("prijenos",brojac);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }};
    }

    public void broji(View view){
        if(provjera==0){
            Count.start();
            brojac++;
            provjera++;
            tekst.setText("Taps " + brojac);
        }else {
            brojac++;
            tekst.setText("Taps " + brojac);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screen after my game activity:

```
package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Score extends Activity {
    int primljeno=1, vrijeme=10000;
    Bundle dodatak;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        TextView prikazati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prikazbodova);
        Intent inte=getIntent();
        dodatak=inte.getExtras();
        primljeno=dodatak.getInt("prijenos");
        prikazati.setText("You tapped "+primljeno+" times");
        spremanje unos = new spremanje(this);
        unos.open();
        vrijeme= unos.getTime();
        vrijeme=vrijeme+125;
        unos.createEntry(vrijeme,primljeno);
        unos.close();

    }



}
```

and here is my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.orion.peky.thetapgame/com.orion.peky.thetapgame.Game}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bodovi: , while compiling: SELECT _id, time, score FROM bodovi
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bodovi: , while compiling: SELECT _id, time, score FROM bodovi
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
            at com.orion.peky.thetapgame.spremanje.getTime(spremanje.java:87)
            at com.orion.peky.thetapgame.Game.onCreate(Game.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

One more thing i have already researched the sql database but it seems i can not find the problem so please don't mark this as a duplicate and there might be more than 1 mistake. Thanks for reading at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this is the result.

> @Override
>       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>           db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + IME_TABLICE + " (" +
>                           KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
>                           KEY_TIME + " INTEGER , " +
>                           KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER )"